# Reach properties from for in-loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-in-loop

I'm creating a simple dice game and right now I'm trying to reach my properties with a for in-loop. Does this make sense? This is the code and the problem shows on the last row.

```
- (IBAction)throwDice {
    //Create an array with the image objects
    NSArray *diceNr = @[_dieOne, _dieTwo, _dieThree, _dieFour, _dieFive];

    //For each image object, get a random number 0-5 
    //and place the associated image for this number in the image object

    for (id dices in diceNr) {
        NSUInteger dieIndex = arc4random_uniform(6);
        NSArray *diceValue = @[@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six"];
        NSNumber *dice = diceValue[dieIndex];
        self.dices.image = dice;        
    }
}
```

Comment: NSString *dice = diceValue[dieIndex];self.dices.image = [UIImage imageNamed:dice]; but if you  use number in array plz define array e.g: NSArray *diceValue = @[@1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6];

Comment: Thank you, but my problem seems to be in the word dices. Here is the error message: Property dices not found on object of type View controller. I want "dices" to change for each object in the diceNr array, how do I do that if not like this?

Comment: id replace with  object's typecasting and user dices instead of self.dices

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

- You assign `NSString*` value from `diceValue` array to `NSNumber*` variable `dice`, and
- You try to assign the string object to `image` property.

Assuming that images `"one"` through `"six"` are in your bundle, with no file extensions, you should be able to do this:

```
UIImage *dice = [UIImage imageNamed:diceValue[dieIndex]];
dices.image = dice;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've changed the NSString/NSNumber, but I guess my problem is in the word dices. Here is the error message: Property dices not found on object of type View controller. I want "dices" to change for each object in the diceNr array, how do I do that if not like this?

Comment: @maraki Remove `self.` then.